# Server to ping to get exact UTC time? And Time zone information?

Tags: ping

I'm making a program that has a function that can only be run at a certain time. I want to make ti so people can't just change the clock time on their computer to make it work. Is there a place I can ping online that will return the exact time?

Also, because I don't want them to be able to cheat with time zones, but I want to incorporate them, is there a way to find out the time zone a host computer is in?

Thanks.

Comment: You might have better luck asking programming questions on Stack Overflow. The time zone question is probably already answered there - and the "reinventing" ntpd inside an app might need more clarification to be answerable.

Comment: What's ntpd? And Stack Overflow no longer accepts questions from me.

Comment: ntpd is a daemon as well as standard system for determining the real time from servers on the internet. You'll have to get on the SO chat or talk with the mods for hints if you have problems with asking questions they would like to see there. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd